# How to hook into node http request?

Tags: node.js

I want to be able to create beforeRequest/afterRequest hooks so every time node makes http call before/after hook is called with all the data ( method, body, url etc) describing the call.

I have been googling but it seems there is nothing no node native method like `http.onBeforeRequest( ({req} => {}))`. If i remember well there were http.ServerRequest in old node which allows what i need but it is no longer there.

Packages that simplifies http request like https://github.com/sindresorhus/got has own implementation but what i'm looking for is something implementation agnostic.

Thx in advance.